# Left Join Linq con valores obtenidos de otro Join

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Tengo esta query en SQL pero no se como transcribir los dos LEFT JOIN del final:

```
SELECT 
    FF.numero, 
    FF.cuo_pla, 
    FF.num_pla,
    PN.Descripcion,
    TN.Nombre
FROM encf EF
JOIN forf FF
    ON EF.numero = FF.numero 
    AND EF.[manual] = FF.[manual]
    AND EF.comproba = FF.comproba
    AND EF.tipo_fac = FF.tipo_fac
    AND EF.sucursal = FF.sucursal
LEFT JOIN Planes PN
    ON FF.num_pla = PN.Numero
LEFT JOIN Tarjetas TN
    ON PN.IdTarjeta = TN.ID
WHERE 
    EF.documento = 123456789
```

Por el momento lo que fui probando fue esto, que es para hacer el primer JOIN de **encf** con **forf** pero no se como hacer los dos ultimos LEFT JOIN

```
var queryEncFor = from enc in db.encf
                              join forF in db.forf on
                                new
                                {
                                    JoinProperty1 = enc.numero,
                                    JoinProperty2 = enc.manual,
                                    JoinProperty3 = enc.comproba,
                                    JoinProperty4 = enc.tipo_fac,
                                    JoinProperty5 = enc.sucursal
                                }
                                equals
                                new
                                {
                                    JoinProperty1 = forFact.numero,
                                    JoinProperty2 = forFact.manual,
                                    JoinProperty3 = forFact.comproba,
                                    JoinProperty4 = forFact.tipo_fac,
                                    JoinProperty5 = forFact.sucursal
                                }
                              where enc.documento == doc
                              select new UnionEncForFact
                              {
                                  numero = enc.numero,
                                  cuo_pla = forF.cuo_pla == null ? 0 : forF.cuo_pla.Value,
                                  num_pla = forF.num_pla
                              };
```

Alguien me ayuda a realizar los LEFT JOIN? Gracias

Comment: Como tienes maparadas als relaciones en entity framework? porque si mapeaste como navegar de una entidad a otra no necesitas definir los left join en la query, lo realizas usando el mapping de la navegacion en las propiedades. Tambien esta raro que necesites tantos campos para definir un join, porque no solo se relacion usando unicamente el numero en lugar de tener que indicar si es manual el tipo y la sucursal estan de mas